# Confusing placement of headlines in posts

Tags: bug, design, markdown

When trying to use simple but good formatting to visually aid in differentiating parts of a slightly longer answer the extents of vertical space seem wrong.

One example:

## This is a headline.

The vertical space visually connecting a headline to the previous paragraph is shorter than the vertical space relating it to the following content. But the following content and the headline form one semantic unit. At least in my reasoning they should be.

Looks to me as if visual layout units are disrupting semantic content units.

Shouldn't this be the other way around – more space separating the previous content a from such an element of order, and optically less space than that to unify headline and following content?

I haven't counted the pixels, but to me it looks as if baselines or x-height are used to calculate equidistance and the effect I see is caused by optically protruding elements?

(Please excuse me if I am just using the syntax wrongly and clarify if it is so, and where I might find guides to improve on this.)

Comment: The problem is that both paragraphs and headers use `1em` for the bottom margin, but em is relative to that element's font size, so the bottom margin ends up taller for headers. Probably should use `1rem` instead to make it consistent in posts.

Comment: The other question is indeed about the same problem. Since it remains unanswered and the problem unresolved I am hesitating to hit "That solved my problem!" But to clarify: nothing I can or should do now about this in my formatting?

Comment: You could add extra space *before* the headline with the following (on four separate lines): `One example:` `<br><br>` `#This is a headline.#` `The vertical space ...`. The two `<br><br>` can optionally be place at the end of the first line. Note that the `<br>` you used in your question is redundant - the spacing remains the same if it is removed,